# http get NodeJS how to get error status code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

OK, I must be dense since I cannot find anywhere how to get the error status codes when using Node.JS `http.get` or `http.request`.

**My code:**

```js
var deferred = $q.defer();
var req = https.get(options, function(response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });
  response.on('end', function() {
    console.log("[evfService] Got user info: " + str);
    deferred.resolve(str);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  deferred.reject(e);
});
```

In that "req.on" bit, what I want is the http status code (i.e. 401, 403, etc.). What I get is a semi-useless error object that does not give me the code or any reference to the response object.

I have tried intercepting in the function(response) callback, but when there is a 404, it never gets called.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried response.statusCode ?

Answer (score 71):

Your callback gets called regardless of the response status code from the server, so within your callback, check `response.statusCode`. That is, a 4xx status code isn't an *error* at the level you're working at; the server responded, it's just that the server responded by saying the resource wasn't available (etc.)

This is [in the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) but characteristically vague. Here's the example they give, with a comment pointing to the relevant bit:

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

If you try that with (say) an unknown resource, you'll see `statusCode: 404`.

So for what you're doing, you may want something like this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

var req = https.get(options, function (response) {
    var str = "";

    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) { // (I don"t know if the 3xx responses come here, if so you"ll want to handle them appropriately
        response.on("data", function() { } ); // ¹
        deferred.reject(/*...with appropriate information, including statusCode if you like...*/);
    }
    else {
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });
        response.on("end", function () {
            console.log("[evfService] Got user info: " + str);
            deferred.resolve(str);
        });
    }
});

req.on("error", function (e) {
    deferred.reject(/*...with appropriate information, but status code is irrelevant [there isn"t one]...*/);
});
```

---

¹ The empty `data` event handler in the branch handling non-OK status codes is there because of this note in the documentation:

> ...if a `'response'` event handler is added, then the data from the response object must be consumed, either by calling `response.read()` whenever there is a `'readable'` event, or by adding a `'data'` handler, or by calling the `.resume()` method. Until the data is consumed, the `'end'` event will not fire. Also, until the data is read it will consume memory that can eventually lead to a 'process out of memory' error.

Since we're passing a function to `https.get`, we're hooking the `'response'` event, which suggests we need to do one of those things (in this case, I've added a do-nothing `data` handler). *Thanks to [Nicolas2bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905822/nicolas2bert) for pointing that out!.*

Comment: Hey there, any ideas on how to perform a retry `(if statusCode != 200)` , from within the response callback?

Comment: @sudosoul: I'd just put the whole thing in a function and, if you want to retry, have that function call itself from the response callback.

Comment: In your startus code condition, don't forget to consume response data to free up memory with res.resume(); From: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest: `Also, until the data is read it will consume memory that can eventually lead to a 'process out of memory' error.`

Comment: @Nicolas2bert - Wow, that's a really surprising requirement. But I read the docs the same way you do, so... Thanks!! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 15):

An error code 400 response is not considered an error by node.js.

Try `response.statusCode` in this:

```
request.on('response', function (response) {});
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a very small example how to get the error code. Just change the `https` to `http` and create an error:

```
var https = require('https')
var username = "monajalal3"
var request = https.get("https://teamtreehouse.com/" + username +".json", function (response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});

request.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error.status);
});
```